# Issues installing Point Cloud Library (PCL) 1.9.1 AllInOne msvc 2017 win32

Tags: point-cloud-library

I have a 32-bit application I am trying to integrate with PCL, so I am trying to use the latest 32-bit PCL library I could find.

While installing "Point Cloud Library (PCL) 1.9.1 AllInOne msvc 2017 win32" on my Windows 10 machine, I get an error "Path too long for registry" and then the installation finishes. If I check the installation everything seems to be OK except when I look at the 3rd party folder for the Eigen library, there are no header files but instead a folder named "eigen3".

I'm using VS 2019 but VS 2017 is installed as well.

Comment: What is "PC 1.9.1 AllInOne"?

Comment: @Botje Point Cloud Library 1.9.1  http://unanancyowen.com/en/pcl191/

Answer (score 1):

You must **Enable** `Win32 long paths`

1. press `Windows key` **+** `R`
2. write `gpedit.msc` then enter
3. Go to : `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem`
4. Click on `Enable Win32 long paths`

[image]

5. check `Enable`

   [image]
6. You probably have to uninstall the old installation and restart another one